# Send all Wifi-Hotspot data through VPN-tunnel with AnyConnect

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn

the following question has the problem - I don't exactly know how to phrase the question due to limited understanding of the exact problem. Hence, I will describe the problem and try my best to phrase it into a question.

I have an Android-Device that has no 4G/LTE-connection. It does support Wifi.
Thus, we used an iPhone to open a Wifi-Hotspot and connect them. 
Now, the plan is, to allow the Android-Device to access the work server.

The iPhone with 4G/LTE itself can not connect to the work server, it has to use a VPN-tunnel to do so. We use Cisco Legacy Anyconnect for that.
Fair enough, set it up and ready to go. 
First test: Yes, iPhone connects, everything works like a charm.
Second test: Android-Device gets internet connection, but has no access to the work server. (Wifi-Hotspot apparently works, but Android-Device doesn't fancy using the VPN-tunnel).

What I think the question is: How do I turn the Android-Device request "Request google" into "ask the vpn-server to request google"?
Or, how do I make the iPhone to route all traffic through the VPN?

Naturally, I checked both the Cisco Documentation and Google for an answer.
Problem is, even when reading the answer I might not recognise the answer due to limited technical grasp of.. well, everything.

What I think could help: Changing the AnyConnect profile to do so. Problem here is that MDM might forbid it. Not quite sure yet.

Thank you for any answer - and might it merely refining the question - and have a nice sunday evening.

Comment: This is a highly unusual request. If VPN is working on the iPhone then it is likely either a limitation/restriction of the iPhone hotspot or the AnyConnect app. You explained the problem well, but I think it is highly unlikely this is possible to do. What you should be doing is installing AnyConnect on the androids so that each initiate their own VPN tunnel.

Comment: I'd love to do that, unfortunately the Android Device is not supporting the appstore and manual installation likely breaks safety regulations.